# Mariadb master-slave replication - can binlog-ignore-db be added to an existing setup?

Tags: mariadb, database-replication

I am using MariaDB 5.5.65 with a single-master, multiple-slave replication setup.

Here's a snippet from my.cnf:

```
binlog_format=ROW
log-bin=/data/mysql/pccodb22-binlog
expire_logs_days=10
max_binlog_size=1024M
server-id = 2      

binlog-ignore-db=mysql
```

Thing is, I forgot to add

```
binlog-ignore-db=information_schema
binlog-ignore-db=performance_schema
```

to the config. Is this safe to do with a live replication setup, or do I have to mysqldump --master-data --all-databases all over again?

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine, no need to reinitialize. Information and performance schemas are virtual rather than physical.

You should really upgrade from MariaDB 5.5.x to at least 10.2.x. 5.5.x is EOL and no longer supported.